# What is new in Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Beta 2 from Beta 1

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone please tell me from where I can read about what are all the improvements and API changes between the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Beta 2 and Beta 1.

Comment: Does it not come with release notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only available information on the changes are the [Release Notes](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26648) (and it only lists breaking changes), but I will summarise major ones here:

- Touch input now occurs on a background thread unless `ManipulationMode=Control` is set on a control
- Image decoding occurs on background thread *by default*, [but it looks like they plan to revert this change before RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/13/off-thread-decoding-of-images-on-mango-how-it-impacts-you-application.aspx)
- `TaiwanCalendar` has been removed for "geopolitical" reasons (?)
- `OnCancel` has been removed from `ScheduledTaskAgent`
- `IsRunningSlowly` has been removed from `GameTimerEventArgs`
- The property types of [`MotionReading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh220685%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) have been changed to reduce dependencies
- IsoStore folders for task/application shared content have been changed
- Background agents are no longer launched automatically in debug mode, instead the new [`LaunchForTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method must be called
- `Microsoft.Devices.YCrCbPixelLayout` has been renamed to `Microsoft.Devices.YCbCrPixelLayout`
- `CaptureResolution` has been dropped in favour of `Size`

Answer (score 1):

The following MSDN page contains a list of all the changes found in the new developer tools:

[What's New In Windows Phone SDK 7.1 - Beta 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516.aspx)

Furthermore you can look at the additional document provided on the download page to see a list of breaking changes based on modified APIs.

Comment: Are all the items listed on this page specific to Beta2. I think most of the items had already been specified in Beta1. Where to check for the changes between Beta2 and Beta1 ?

Answer (score 0):

the beta 2 will have facilities to deploy the apps to developer phones running the beta os. they have also improved certain parts of the api after feedback from developers.

Comment: I think the OP is wanting specifics.